# Почему строка 'fname' должна завершаться нулем?

Tags: c, строки

Встретил предупреждение о том, что строка `fname` должна завершаться нулем. С чем это связано?

```
void DataInitialization()  //Инициализация данных
{
    FILE* F;
    char fname[100];
    printf("Укажите имя файла, в котором будет хранится база данных (как на примере: text.txt)\n-> ");
    scanf_s("%s", fname, sizeof(fname));
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    if ((F = fopen(fname, "w+")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Невозможно открыть для чтения файл \n");
        return;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любая строка, представленная массивом `char` или `char *` (что, по сути, почти одно и то же) должна заканчиваться нулём. Но не символом `'0'`, а нулевым байтом `'\0'`. То есть символом, КОД которого равен нулю. Такие строки ещё называют нуль-терминированными.

Делается это потому, что строка хранится только в виде указателя на первый символ (того самого `fname`, который, хоть и объявлен как массив, на деле – от же указатель). Далее идут сколько-то символов подряд в памяти. Сколько именно, функция не знает. Даже если Вы указали размер массива. Следовательно, чтобы ей понять, где же в памяти всё-таки кончается эта строка, начало которой хранится в указателе, и нужен нулевой байт. Как только функция его видит, считает, что строка закончилась.

Сделаем простую проверку, вставим нуль-символ в середину строки и посмотрим, как её выведет программа:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
  char x[100] = "Hello, \0world!\n";

  printf("%s", x);
}
```

В результате, как и ожидалось, получим не полную строку, а только ту часть, что стоит до `'\0'`, оставшаяся часть будет обрезана, т.к., как уже упоминалось выше, нуль-символ считается концом строки, а значит всё, что после, не выводится.

Также, думаю, стоит отметить, что, когда Вы присваиваете строковой переменной значение в кавычках, как здесь `char x[100] = "Hello, world!\n";`, символ `'\0'` автоматически добавляется в конец такой строки. И если в кавычки вписать ровно 100 символов, оставив размер массива таким же, возможно, случится что-то плохое или программа просто не скомпилится, т.к. не останется места для того самого нуль-символа.

Дополнительная информация [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Comment: т.е. чтобы исправить такое предупреждение необходим в строке ввода, указать нулевой байт. Я только не понимаю, где именно его нужно поставить?

Comment: @rendy Покажите полный текст предупреждения

Comment: Возможно, строка "fname" не завершается нулем.

Comment: @rendy `scanf_s` сама завершает строку нулём. Предупреждение, скорее всего, сделано на тот случай, если Вы что-то напутаете с количеством символов.

Comment: это предупреждение бесполезное получается? иначе как можно напутать с количеством символов.

Comment: @rendy Напутать с количеством? Легко! Сделать размер массива меньше, чем будет введено символов, а число считываемых символов в третьем аргументе `scanf_s` поставить больше. Тогда `'\0'` может не попасть в массив и что-нибудь сломается из-за некорректного имени.

Comment: `Как только компилятор его видит, считает, что строка закончилась.` Что за чушь? Компилятор ничего не видит... Просто функция которая будет получать этот указатель, будет искать тот самый `\0`, дабы найти конец строки...

Comment: @ヒミコ, согласен, формулировка получилась глупая, исправлю